# User input in HTML being placed into links (Using APIS) (JSON + AJAX + HTML)

Tags: html, json, syntax

I get SyntaxError: Unexpected string literal 'y'. Expected '}' to end an object literal whilst trying to place my users input into the link. I am confused on what to do. I saved it as Y to and then placed it into the link, before this I can run it with a random number. I need Y to be an integer (3 numbers) If I was to add a three digit into where Y is the link it would be able to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<form id = "busform">
Bus Stop: <input name="SMS code" type = "text"><br>
    <button onclick="get_times() ;">Get bus times</button>
</form>
  <body id="bodi">
    <script>
      function get_times() {
        var x,y ;
        x = document.getElementById("busform");
        y = x.elements["SMS code"].value;

          $.ajax({
              type: 'GET',
                       url: 'https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Line/''y''Arrivals?app_id=&app_key=',
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(data){
                  $("#times").html("");
                  var sorted = data.sort(function (a, b) {
                          if (a.timeToStation > b.timeToStation) {
                            return 1;
                          }
                          if (a.timeToStation < b.timeToStation) {
                            return -1;
                          }
                          return 0;
                  });
                  $.each(data, function(key,value){
                      var line = value.lineName;
                      var stop_name = value.stationName;
                      var destination = value.destinationName;
                      var time = value.timeToStation;
                      time = parseInt(time/60);
                      time < 1 ? time = "due" : time = time+" min";
                      $("#times").append(line+" "+stop_name+" "+destination+" "+time+"<br>")
                  });
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

the `'` around "y" in the url is illegal，if you want to concat y's value into url，you should use '+' to concat it

Comment: How would I do this?

Comment: `url: 'https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Line/' + y + 'Arrivals?app_id=&app_key='`，I think this is what you want

Comment: Once I've placed it in the code runs but has no output? Is there another way of storing user input and then placing it inside that link?

Comment: can you give an example of what `y` is ? It seem likes that the generated url is not correct, because generally url does not has this pattern, maybe you miss `/` before "Arrivals", you can check the api docs to see if the generated url is correct. And, you  can see the request result by browser's devtools

Comment: Y could be a 3 digit number for example 275, 212. Yes it should have a / before arrivals however it does not run still with that